# LibreOffice4.2 Fatal Error

Tags: 14.04, software-center, libreoffice, su

[image]

Does it mean to say that **I am not the root user ?** But I am the root and have both **sudo** and **su** access. So why don't I have the **sufficient access to open Libre Office?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you previously run libreoffice as a superuser with sudo? If so, some configuration files under .config may have been overwritten and a normal user (you) can't modify them.

If you don't have any special configuration, you can remove the whole directory and start libreoffice again like this:

```
sudo rm -rvf /home/algosig/.config/libreoffice
```

Then, restart libreoffice again and see if the error persists.

Comment: By the way, if you ever need to run libreoffice, or any graphic application as superuser, better use gksu instead of sudo.